# AngularJS - choosing between lists in view

Tags: angularjs, list, view, controller

I'm working in angularjs and basically what I'm trying to do is prepopulate a dropdown list depending on the organization name. Now, the following code DOES prepopulate the correct values but whenever I go to execute the code, it cannot reference the properties defined in the list.

I have two lists defined in my controller:

```
listOne = [{name : 'NameOne', id : 'IdOne'}];
listTwo = [{name : 'NameTwo', id : 'NameTwo'}];
```

(there's more items in these lists... but just so you get the point)

In my view I have the following:

```
<div ng-if="$root.sessionObj.name.org != 'OrgName'">
    <select name="domain" id = "domain" class="form-control"
         required="true"
         ng-options="domain as domain.name for domain in listOne"
         ng-model="selectedDomain">
         <option value=""/>
     </select>
</div>
<div ng-if="$root.sessionObj.name.org=='OrgName'">
     <select name="domain id="domain" class="form-control"
         required="true"
         ng-options="domain as domain.name for domain in listTwo"
         ng-model="selectedDomain">
         <option value="" />
     </select>
</div>
```

Whenever I go to execute my code, I keep receiving a type error that states "unable to get property 'name' of undefined or null reference. Does anyone know what I could be doing wrong? I tried a bunch of different things, including wrapping my divs in the controller that defines these lists, but that also did not work. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I don't believe you need an empty `option` tag when using `ng-options`

Answer (score 0):

That error could either be from $root.sessionObj or domain from your html. Do you have both of those defined on your scope?

Comment: I do. whenever I remove the ifs and only have one list populate the dropdown, it works fine. but whenever I put in the if condition if complains. @Scott Schwalbe

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! Turns out it was caused by something completely not related to the list.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the undefined 'name' is coming from '$root.sessionObj.name' and not from 'domain.name'.

Make sure that '$root.sessionObj' is not undefined.